# Applying setOnInfoWindowClickListener in a loop to every marker on Maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have multiple number of markers on map and getting all the data from server. When I put markers on map U am also attaching OnInfoWindowClickListener but every time I click the info windows it gave the same result on clicking every info window.

```
for(int l =0;l<userDataArrayList.size();l++){
                         MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(userDataArrayList.get(l).getLat()), Double.parseDouble(userDataArrayList.get(l).getLng()))).title(pokename[userDataArrayList.get(l).getCharacterId()-1]).snippet("Click Here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(pokeImgID[userDataArrayList.get(l).getCharacterId() - 1]));

                            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(opt);


                            final int a = l;
                            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new AmazonMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                                final Dialog Dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                                                System.out.println(a);
                                                Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.seen_detail);
                                                Dialog.show();
                                                ImageView IMage = (ImageView) Dialog.findViewById(R.id.Img);
                                                IMage.setImageResource(ImgID[userDataArrayList.get(a).getCharacterId()]);
                                        }
                                });

                    }
```

My **Question** is how can I have result according to markers data. Not same data for every marker.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should implement an InfoWindowAdapter. Google it, you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: @SripadRaj i will be able to make a custom info by using Info windowAdapter but still question is same that how i will be able to get different data according to a specific marker when i click on infowindow.